# cannot add custom css in cms page layout - magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2, xml, frontend

I can't add my custom css in cms->page->design->layout, my code
[image]

```
<head>
  <css src="Magento_Theme::css/mycss.css" /> 
</head>
<referenceContainer name="content"> 
    <container name="home-page-full-block" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="home-page-full-block">  
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage_block" template="Magento_Theme::mypage/my_home_page.phtml"></block>
   </container>   
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: show your CSS file path.

Comment: /home/root/www/pub/static/frontend/Developer/shop/en_US/css/mycss.css

Comment: <head> cannot be support by `layout update xml` at magento2

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug in Magento 2. The fix for this was planned for the 2.2.4 release. But is know scheduled for the 2.3.0 release. For now this will not work.

further information: [check this link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4454)